# Dmenu Processes Forked by Bash?

Tags: bash, fork, dmenu

I was looking at the output of `pstree`, and realised that processes that I started using `dmenu` seem to fork from `bash`.

What is the reasoning behind this?  And is there any way I can make `dmenu` behave like `gmrun` and other application launchers and only launch the process?

---

**EDIT:** The `dmenu` manpage says that the shell execution behavior is correct for `dmenu_run`.  Figuring out how to not make the shell persist after launching the program is what I am still looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking about it on the ArchLinux forum after a little while.

Here is what `/usr/bin/dmenu_run` should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cachedir=${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-"$HOME/.cache"}
if [ -d "$cachedir" ]; then
    cache=$cachedir/dmenu_run
else
    cache=$HOME/.dmenu_cache # if no xdg dir, fall back to dotfile in ~
fi
exec $(
    IFS=:
    if stest -dqr -n "$cache" $PATH; then
        stest -flx $PATH | sort -u | tee "$cache" | dmenu "$@"
    else
        dmenu "$@" < "$cache"
    fi
)
```

Comment: That still kept `dmenu_run` as a parent process. What I did was to replace `exec` with `app=`. And after that do a `exec $app &; disown %1` which detaches the application, so it has no other parent than the system.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking at `dmenu_run`. The list of applications is populated by using the shell, and is passed back to it in determining what to run -- dmenu doesn't launch anything, it just passes back what you selected to whatever is listening, and that acts upon it. The shell is doing the heavy lifting, which is why it is required.

Answer (score 1):

`dmenu` doesn't start processes, it just prints the selected item to stdout. It's up to something else - probably your window manager - to actually execute the program you selected.

You will need to provide more information on what is calling `dmenu` for anyone to help further.

Comment: Both DWM's Alt+Enter and launching dmenu_run from `urxvt` or `gmrun` will cause bash to be a parent process of whatever is started by `dmenu`.  Hopefully this is what you were asking about.
Is there any way to, for example, prepend `exec` to all commands launched by dmenu so that `bash` is no a parent afterward?

Comment: My version of `dmenu_run` (4.0 +xft patch) doesn't show the same behavior. Bypassing `dmenu_run` and running `exec $(dmenu_path | dmenu)` may be a quick fix. If you have an older version, updating might be another fix.

Comment: I am using the Arch Linux package of dmenu-4.5, so it isn't a problem of an old package.  I'll try installing `dmenu` from source and see if anything changes.

Comment: There wasn't any real way to configure the installation from source code, so I'm at a loss as to why behavior is different than yours.

Comment: I'm using the `dmenu-xft` [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dmenu-xft/). Just updated to 4.5-1, and still can't reproduce the behavior.